# Error Creating the Web Proxy specified in system.net/defaultproxy

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

Hi I am new to C# development. and I was given the job to create a C# WPF stand alone application, which creates an outlook template and open that in outlook application.

In order to open the outlook, I ma using outlook._mailitem and below is a snapshot of the code

```
try
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMailItem.To = EmailUrl;
    oMailItem.BCC = "CarerGatewayReferrals@wellways.org";
    oMailItem.HTMLBody = HTMLBody;
    oMailItem.Subject = SubjectText;
    oMailItem.Display(true);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ", Please contact NCSP BI Team");
}
```

Now after building the application, I placed the executable file in our Company Server, so that everyone can access this application. Unfortunately due to the requirments I can't publish this application.

Whenever a user runs the application, and reach to this point,when the application needs to open Outlook, the program catches the exception and prompts the following message

"Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section"

I tried to debug the program, but found no issues at my development machine. And I think the error is occuring when the program is trying to open Outlook. I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Please some one help.

Comment: Does that code run in a web server (IIS)?

Comment: Hi Dimitry, No, its a stand alone WPF application, its executable is placed on a network drive which people are using

Comment: You might want to add your app.config file. Also, maybe you're admin but your users are not - this could explain the different behavior.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, what do you mean by adding your app.config ?